# python duration more than 24 hours

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time, duration

i'm trying to handle a time format like the following:
148:54:13
that means, durations expressed as 1 up to thousands of hours, including minutes and seconds (hhhh...:mm:ss).

Is there any way python can read this as a duration?
if not, how can i convert it into a readable time format/duration?

I've managed importing the data frame and searched the web for a solution for about an hour but didn't find any solution. I hope you can help me with this.

many thanks in advance
dom

Comment: If you're using pandas - have you tried using applying `pd.Timedelta` to your column? `pd.Timedelta('148:54:13')` will give you `Timedelta('6 days 04:54:13')` for instance...?

Comment: @JonClements: Thanks, Jon. That worked out for me. Kind regards